# Javascript Syntax Colon - Need Help (Not Json object or ternary)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I came across this strange javascript syntax and I'm trying to understand how the colon is being used within and after the first function parameter. Also, if anyone can explain Array, that would be awesome.

```
  getDataSource: function(mediaItems: Array<any>): ListView.DataSource{
    return this.state.resultsData.cloneWithRows(mediaItems);
  },
```

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a type annotation.

Comment: That's a type annotation - [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) or [Flow](https://flowtype.org/docs/type-annotations.html).